# inject instance of ability using casl library

Tags: vue.js, casl

With the latest version of casl that supports only vue 3, an instance can be created like this:

```
import { ABILITY_TOKEN } from '@casl/vue';

export default {
inject: {
$ability: { from: ABILITY_TOKEN }
}
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@casl/vue

how can this be achieved with the previous version of casl plugin for vue?